# jq: slicing array based on argument

Tags: json, bash, casting, command-line-arguments, jq

I am trying to slice an array in jq where the end index is passed as an argument from the shell (bash):

```
end_index=7
cat obj.json | jq --arg eidx $end_index, '.arr[0:$eidx]'
```

This works as expected when the index is hard-coded

```
cat obj.json | jq '.arr[0:7]'
```

but in the example at the top, I get an error message

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Start and end indices of an array slice must be numbers
```

I suspect this might be to do with how jq handles variable substitution within the slice operator `[:]`, but none of my attempts to solve the problem, e.g. by enclosing the variable name in curly braces `.arr[0:${eidx}]`, has worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You can convert a string to a number using `tonumber`, as in:

```
jq --arg eidx 1 '.arr[0:($eidx|tonumber)]'
```

2. If your jq is sufficiently recent, you can use `--argjson` instead of `--arg`:

```
jq --argjson eidx 1 '.arr[0:$eidx]'
```

Comment: --argjson did the job for me

Answer (score 1):

When you pass an argument via `--arg` it is treated as a string, not an int:

> --arg name value:
>
> This option passes a value to the jq program as a predefined variable. If you run jq with --arg foo bar, then $foo is available in the program and has the value "bar". **Note that value will be treated as a string, so --arg foo 123 will bind $foo to "123"**.

From [the docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) (emphases added)

so it would seem that you cannot use `--arg` to pass a value to be used in a slice.  In this example, you could just use the shell expansion though:

```
jq ".arr[0:$end_index]" obj.json
```

the double quotes will have the shell expand your variable before passing it to `jq` (though other expansions will happen to, so make sure you mean them to happen.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out interpretation as a string. Shell expansion doesn't always work for more complex jq commands, which is why I was using --arg in the first place